# What is the difference between -D and -L in SSH tunneling options?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Besides the fact that -D is a SOCKS proxy which operates through one port, is there any other differences? Specifically, would there be any differences in terms of HTTPS connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `-D` and `-L` is how the destination server is specified, which you already mentioned. There are no differences for HTTPS; both options provide you a channel for TCP connections without any regards to the data transferred.